# Highcharts : style (css)

Tags: css, highcharts

Here is a bar chart showing dates. I'm trying to stylize it and to save space (but also because it is useless).
Do you know how we remove the green square and the text "data by year" please?

Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      zoomType: 'x'
    },
    colors:[
      '#d8d826'
    ],
    legend:{
      itemStyle:{
        fontSize:'10px',
        font:'10pt',
        color:'#000000'
      }
    },
    title:{
      style:{
        fontSize:'0px'
      }
    },
    subtitle:{
      style:{
        fontSize:'0px'
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
        // NOTE: There is an interesting bug here where not all labels will be shown when the chart is redrawn.
      // I'm not certain why this is occuring, and I've tried different methods to no avail. I'll check with Highcharts.
      categories: ['1960','1961','1962','1963','1964','1965','1966','1967','1968','1969','1970','1971','1972','1973','1974','1975','1976','1977','1978','1979','1980','1981','1982','1983','1984','1985','1986','1987','1988','1989','1990','1991','1992','1993','1994','1995','1996','1997','1998','1999','2000','2001','2002','2003','2004','2005','2006','2007','2008','2009','2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016'],
      tickmarkPlacement: 'on', tickInterval: 1,
      minRange: 1   // set this to allow up to one year to be viewed
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 15,
      title: {
        text: 'Number',
        style:{
          fontSize:'0px'
        }
      }
    },
    tooltip: {        
      shared: false,
      useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        pointPadding: 0.2,
        borderWidth: 0
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'data by year',
      data: [49.9,83.6,48.9,69.1,83.6,40.9,69.9,83,28.9,40.9,81.6,24.9,46.4,49.9,83.6,48.9,69.1,83.6,40.9,69.9,83,28.9,40.9,81.6,24.9,46.4,49.9,83.6,48.9,69.1,83.6,40.9,69.9,83,28.9,40.9,81.6,24.9,46.4,49.9,83.6,48.9,69.1,83.6,40.9,69.9,83,28.9,40.9,81.6,24.9,46.4,49.9,83.6,48.9,69.1,50]
    }]
  });

    // on change handler for both sliders
  $('.mySlider').bind('change', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    // use setExtremes to set the x-axis ranges based on the values in the sliders
    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes($('input[name="slider1"]').val(), $('input[name="slider2"]').val());
  });

});
```

You can see the result in https://jsfiddle.net/uvat8u05/9/

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the legend:

```
legend:{
    enabled: false
},
```

Updated fiddle:

- https://jsfiddle.net/uvat8u05/12/

Comment: Awesome ! Thank you !